# Stored procedure with a temp table running multiple times on different SQL task in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure which I want to run on multiple SQL tasks inside a SSIS package. The stored procedure contains temp tables.

Also, each SQL task will execute the stored procedure with different parameters than others.

My question: IS IT SAFE TO RUN THEM? DOES SSIS RUN SPs THROUGH DIFFERENT SESSIONS?

Can anyone explain... by the way, I am using SQL Server 2019. I have tried it for some tasks, but I am not sure, yet it is okay or not to do?

Comment: What do you mean by is it safe to run them? Without knowing what your SP does it's pretty hard for us to comment

Comment: Every connection to SQL Server is a separate session.

Comment: Unless you set RetainSameConnection to true: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/

Comment: How do you define temp tables? #someTable? ##otherTable? tempdb..notReallyATempTableButWillHangAroundUntilTheInstanceRestarts?

Comment: Temp table names are not simply `#tab`, they actually have a bunch of random numbers and underscores prefixed to them which are basically hidden from you during use (`select name from tempdb.sys.tables`). Assuming you're using separate sessions, each session will create a unique clone of the tables schema and you should be fine. If you are reusing connections, you may have problems. You can also add `drop table if exists #tab` if you are reusing conns but are confident each run should destroy/remake the table.